# How to measure the quality of my code?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

I have some experience with coding but one of the biggest questions which annoying me is how to improve my code.

I every time check the **complexity**, **readability** and the **correctness** of the code but my question is how I can measure the size and the time of specific commands.

**For example:**

when I have the next problem:

`A` is an integer

`B` is an integer

`C` is an integer

`if` - A is bigger the B assign `C=A`

`else` - `C=B`

for that problem, we have 2 simple solutions -

**1.** use if-else statement

**2.** use ternary operator

for a dry check of the size of the file before compilation, i get that the second solution file is less from the first in a half (for 1000000 operations I get a difference of some MB).

**My question** is how I can measure the time difference between some codes which make the same operation but with **different commands**, and how much the compiler makes optimization for commands which is close like the 2 from the example.

Comment: To be honest, it's hard to measure that low time-frames. I'm very interested in replies from people since measuring which one is better is fairly straightforward (write down the time after each execution and after 1000000 operations get an average), this won't give you precise execution times but rather which one is faster in average. But how to get precise executions times is a mystery to me also.

Comment: @Ante - If the difference is so small that it can't be measured, why do we care in the first place?

Comment: Execution time != fitness for purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyse the Time Complexity of the two algorithms. If they seem competitive,

**Benchmark**.

Provide a sufficient large input for your problem, so that the timing is not affected by other -OS- overheads.

Develop two programs that solve the same problem, but with a different approach.

I have some methods in [Time measurements](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1651-2/) to time code. Example:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct timeval wallclock_t;

void wallclock_mark(wallclock_t *const tptr)
{
    gettimeofday(tptr, NULL);
}

double wallclock_since(wallclock_t *const tptr)
{
    struct timeval  now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);

    return difftime(now.tv_sec, tptr->tv_sec)
            + ((double)now.tv_usec - (double)tptr->tv_usec) / 1000000.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    wallclock_t  t;
    double  s;

    wallclock_mark(&t);

    /*
     * Solve the problem with Algorithm 1
    */

    s = wallclock_since(&t);
    printf("That took %.9f seconds wall clock time.\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

You will get a time measurement. Then you use solve the problem with "Algorithm 2", for example, and compare these measurements.

---

PS: Or you could check the Assembly code of every approach, for a more low level approach.

Answer (score 5):

The best and most direct way is to check an assembly code generated by your compiler at different optimization level.

**//EDIT**

I didn't mention benchmarking, because your question is about checking the difference between two source codes using different language constructions to do the same job.

Don't get me wrong, **benchmaking is recommended solution of assuring general software performance, but in this particular scenario, it might be unreliable**, because of extremely small execution time frames basic operations have.
Even when you calculate amortized time from multiple runs, the difference might be to much dependend on the OS and environment and thus pollute your results.

To learn more on the subject I recommend [this talk from Cppcon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWxSZcpeS8Q), it's actaully kinda interesting.

**But most importantly**,

**Quick peek under the hood by exploring assembly code can give you information whether two statements has been optimized into exactly same code**. It might not be so clear from benchmarking the code.

In the case you asked (if vs tenary operator) it should always lead to same machine code, because tenary operator is just a syntactic sugar for if and physically it's actually the same operation.

Comment: If you have sufficient experience optimizing code for speed and have thus acquired a good general recollection of Agner Fog's instruction tables; sometimes all it takes is a quick glance at the assembly output to determine the better code... or that it makes no difference when optimization is on and you should just use the simpler code.  It becomes less and less difficult with more and more experience.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways is using time function in the bash shell followed by execution repeated for a large number of times. This will show which is better. And make A template which does nothing of the two and you can know the buffer time.

Please take the calculation for many cases and compare averages before making any conclusions.